# Cannot see geoJSOn source in mapbox/react

Tags: reactjs, mapbox, geojson, mapbox-gl-js

I have the following simple map in a react/mapbox project
. I try to pass a geoJSON as a source and then add it as a layer.

Code is based on mapbox tutorial [here](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/use-mapbox-gl-js-with-react/) and react/mapbox tutorial [here](https://www.lostcreekdesigns.co/writing/a-complete-guide-to-sources-and-layers-in-react-and-mapbox-gl-js/)

```
import { useRef, useEffect, useState } from 'react';   
import mapboxgl from '!mapbox-gl'; // eslint-disable-line import/no-webpack-loader-syntax
mapboxgl.accessToken = '123';

  const Map = () => { 

const mapContainer = useRef(null);
const map = useRef(null);
const [lng, setLng] = useState(-7.3895);
const [lat, setLat] = useState(52.8695);
const [zoom, setZoom] = useState(16);


useEffect(() => {
  if (map.current) return; // initialize map only once

  map.current = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: mapContainer.current, 
    style:'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
    center: [lng, lat],
    zoom: zoom,
    projection: 'mercator'
  });//map 

  map.current.on('load', () => {

      map.current.addSource('countries', {
        type: 'geojson', 
        data: 'http://localhost:3000/test4326.geojson'
        //data:'https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/4347f3565fbe4d5dbb97b016768b8907_0.geojson'

      });

      map.current.addLayer({
        id: 'countries',
        type: 'fill',//line
        source: 'countries', 
        paint: { 
          'fill-outline-color': 'rgba(0,0,0,0.1)',
          'fill-color': 'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)'
        }
        //  paint: {
        //    "line-color": "#15cc09",
        //    "line-width": 4,
        //  },
      });
      
      console.log('load')

  });//load

  map.current.on('move', () => {

    setLng(map.current.getCenter().lng.toFixed(4));
    setLat(map.current.getCenter().lat.toFixed(4));
    setZoom(map.current.getZoom().toFixed(2));
    console.log('map move');
  });//move

});//useEffect
 

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Map</h3> 
      <div>Longitude: {lng} | Latitude: {lat} | Zoom: {zoom}</div>
      <div ref={mapContainer} className="map-container" />
    </div>
  )

}

export default Map
```

I downloaded the arcgis data, its EPSG 4326, it has lines, so I give it the right style. It loads on the map. Everything works fine.

I created a geoJSON with polygons, type is `fill`, I set the right styles for fill, I try to load it from my localhost react project. I reproject it to EPSG 4326. I see no errors in the console, but I cannot see the polygons.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

EDIT

I donwloaded the arcgis geoJSON and serve it from my react localhost in the source like

```
  map.current.addSource('countries', {
    type: 'geojson', 
    data: 'http://localhost:3000/UTA_Routes_and_Most_Recent_Ridership.geojson'
    //data:'https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/4347f3565fbe4d5dbb97b016768b8907_0.geojson'

  });
```

Still works fine, compared to my `data: 'http://localhost:3000/test4326.geojson'` I dont know what am I doing wrong. Its probably something in the `test4326.geojson` file

Thanks

Comment: Try to run this with deployed version, might be issue with `localhost` couldn't get data over `https`.

Comment: Nice idea, but as you can see if I put another geoJSON file in the data it works fine, so its something in the file, the projection or the position of the data

Comment: Try pasting the geojson in https://geojsonlint.com/, it will let you know if there's any issues with it.  If it's valid, maybe it's a loading issue as mentioned above.

Also, even though it says EPSG 4326 you may want to inspect the coordinates to see if they are actually reasonable long/lat coordinates for where you expect them to be in the world.